# Functioning of sizeof() operator in C++

Tags: c++, std, sizeof

I wrote a simple program in order to understand the functioning of the function of the standard c++ library **sizeof()**.

It follows:

```
const char* array[] = {
                          "1234",
                          "5678"
                          };

    std::cout << sizeof(array) << std::endl;//16
    std::cout << sizeof (array[0]) << std::endl;//8

    std::cout << printf("%lu\n",sizeof (char) );//1
    std::cout << printf("%lu\n",sizeof (int) );//24
    std::cout << printf("%lu\n",sizeof (float) );//24
    std::cout << printf("%lu",sizeof (double) );//281
```

It is possible to see by the output reported the characters has dimension 1 byte in my OS, as
expectable. But I do not understand why the dimension of '''array[0]''' is 8, as it contains 4 charcaters and at least other 2 charcaters for the end sequence "\n" which is contained in a string. Thus, I supposed that the number of bytes occupied by the first element of the array should be 6 and not 8.
Moreover, if I increase/decrease the number of charcaters contained in the first element of the array, the its size does not change.
Clearly, I am wrong. If somebody can explain me this functioning, I would really appreciate.
Thanks,

Comment: `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of *the pointer*, not what the pointer might point to.

Comment: `std::cout << printf...` you are printing the output of printf and the return value of printf. `printf` is printing the sizeof with newlines and then additionally `std::cout` prints the return value of `printf`

Comment: Also note that the correct `printf` format for the type `size_t` (which is what `sizeof` returns) is `%zu`. And why are you even using `printf` here? And why do you print the return-value of `printf`?

Comment: Double on your system is reallllllly 281! Wow :-)

Answer (score 6):

> I wrote a simple program in order to understand the functioning of the function of the standard c++ library sizeof().

**Wrong terminology.** Please read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (a C++ standard) and the wikipage on [sizeof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).

**[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is a compile-time operator, *not* a function**. If `v` is some variable, `sizeof(v)` only depends on the *type* of `v` and never on its *value* (in contrast, for most functions `f`, the value of `f(v)` depends upon the value of `v`).

And a good way to understand something about C++ is to refer to documents like standards or good web pages about it.

> If somebody can explain me

Yes. Read a good book about C++. [This one](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) is written by the main designer of C++. Try to understand more and better the (difficult) [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of C++. You could also study the source code of existing open source C++ compilers such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/) (thus effectively using one of your [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) [freedoms](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)).

BTW, with a lot of pain you might find C++ implementations with `sizeof(int)` being 1 (e.g. for some [DSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor) processors). On cheap 32 bits [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) processors (those in cheap mobile phones today, for instance; then you would probably use some [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)) or on some [Raspberry Pis](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) (or perhaps some [mainframes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainframe_computer)) you could have `sizeof(array[0])` or `sizeof(void*)` being 4 even in 2019.

Comment: I don't think remarks like "Read a good book about C++" are relevant for "answers!" Such are OK in comments - but if you post an answer, then make it an answer, not a lecture!

Comment: I don't have time to write many pages about `sizeof` and if I did I am sure people would find my answer too long. The "someone" I am refering to is called B.Stroustrup. And I gave two relevant hyperlinks before mentioning that book

Comment: I can understand @BasileStarynkevitch hints how to go forward after the answer and avoid just a series of follow up questions and how to learn are making sense to me. He still wrote an quality answer to the question.

Comment: My answer might not be decent (but what would be an indecent answer? Something with pornography ??) but I am trying hard to make it correct. Remember that I am not a native English speaker

Comment: I'm not sure if suggesting a complete newbie to go read source code of GCC or LLVM is a good advice.

Comment: @patentfox It might be, at least to teach him how difficult his question could be. And OP could also run a (DWARF enabled) `g++` from the debugger

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for your advice. I supposed it was a difficult question and, clearly, I have not time to read everything you linked. Although, you answered in an exhaustive manner.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the meaning of the somewhat confusing output values you see!

First, the `sizeof(array)` and `sizeof(array[0])` (where your output method is fine). You have delared/defined `array` as an array of two `char*` values, each of which is a pointer. The size of a pointer on your system is 8 bytes, so the total size of `array` is: **8 * 2 = 16**. For array[0]: this is a single pointer, so its size is simply 8 bytes.

Does all this make sense so far? If so, then let's look at the second part of your code …

The values for `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(double)` are, ***on your system***, in order, 1, 4, 4, and 8. These values are actually being output! However, as you are also outputting the return value of `printf()`, which is the number of characters it has written, you are getting the extra values, "2", "2", "2" and "1" inserted (in a confusing, and possibly undefined, order), for the four calls (the last one has no newline, so it's only one character; all others are one digit + newline = 2 characters).

Change the second part of your code as follows, to get the correct outputs:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char));   //1
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));    //4
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(float));  //4
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(double)); //8
```

Comment: You could have C++ implementations where `sizeof(int)`  is 1. I think some DSP processors have that. And on some machines from the previous century with some C++ compiler, you had `sizeof(int) == 2`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But not on the OP's system! My answer was specific to his/her question, not a general statement on C++ implementations.

Comment: this is still not correct. You must use `%zu` or UB will happen